# Connection Reset error when closing AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, kotlin, http, sockets, asynchronous

I'm experimenting with a simple HTTP1.1 server in Kotlin in order to try and reproduce a more complex problem where content seems to get cut off when closing the `AsynchronousSocketChannel`

`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)`

First a helper function to make debugging easier:

```
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline fun ByteArray.debug(): String = this.map {
    when (it) {
        '\t'.code.toByte() -> "\\t"
        '\r'.code.toByte() -> "\\r"
        '\n'.code.toByte() -> "\\n\n"
        else -> "${it.toInt().toChar()}"
    }
}.toTypedArray().joinToString(separator = "") { it }
```

and here's the whole simplified web server with all its imports which you should be able to copy and paste into a `.kt` file to run:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

fun main() {

    val len = 1_000_000

    val server =
        AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(InetSocketAddress(5555))

    while (true) {
        val channel = server.accept().get()

        val body = "#".repeat(len)
        val headers = mutableListOf<String>()
        headers.add("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
        headers.add("Server: Test Server")
        headers.add("Content-Type: text/plain")
        headers.add("Connection: close")
        headers.add("Content-Length: ${body.length}")
        val header = headers.joinToString(separator = "\r\n") + "\r\n\r\n"

        println("==== header (size=${header.toByteArray().size})")
        println(header.toByteArray().debug())
        println("==== body (size=${body.toByteArray().size})")
        val data = "$header$body".toByteArray()
        println("==== data (size=${data.size})")

        println(data.debug())
        channel.write(
            ByteBuffer.wrap(data),
            30,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            channel,
            object : CompletionHandler<Int?, AsynchronousSocketChannel> {
                override fun completed(result: Int?, channel: AsynchronousSocketChannel) {
                    println(result)
                    channel.close()
                }

                override fun failed(exc: Throwable?, channel: AsynchronousSocketChannel) {
                    channel.close()
                }
            })

    }

}
```

Running it and opening the browser at `localhost:5555`, I'm greeted by a Connection Reset

[image]

Looking at the browser Network console, I can see that the response headers look correct:

[image]

Looking at the output, I can see that it too is correct and matches what we're seeing in the browser Network Console, and the `1000110` at the end which is printed inside the Completion Handler, matches the total size of the data yet nothing renders and the browser complains about a connection reset.

```
==== header (size=110)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Test Server\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Length: 1000000\r\n
\r\n

==== body (size=1000000)
==== data (size=1000110)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Test Server\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Length: 1000000\r\n
\r\n
#####################################################################################.......
1000110
```

If I add a Thread.sleep before the `channel.close()`, it works correctly, but then obviously the browser will wait for a full second before the connection is available again, so it's definitely not a solution.

```
channel.write(
    ByteBuffer.wrap(data),
    30,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    channel,
    object : CompletionHandler<Int?, AsynchronousSocketChannel> {
        override fun completed(result: Int?, channel: AsynchronousSocketChannel) {
            println(result)
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            channel.close()
        }

        override fun failed(exc: Throwable?, channel: AsynchronousSocketChannel) {
            channel.close()
        }
    })
```

[image]

One of the responses suggested to call channel.shutdownOutput() followed by a channel.read() before calling close()

```
override fun completed(result: Int?, channel: AsynchronousSocketChannel) {
    println(result)
    channel.shutdownOutput()
    channel.read(ByteBuffer.allocate(1)).get()
    channel.close()
}
```

if I'm using `allocate(1)`, it doesn't fix the issue, but `allocate(very-big-number)` does work which is actually no different than just calling Thread.sleep here.

If I deploy it to AWS with a short Thread.sleep behind a load balancer, I run into a
`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)` which means it's getting some data written, but the stream gets cut off before the load balancer could read all the data, effectively the same as the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)` error.

[image]

What is the correct way to close the AsynchronousSocketChannel without hitting connection reset errors or content length mismatch errors in the browser?

**EDIT**: here's the more full-fledged demo where I can still reproduce the error. In this example I'm first reading the request before writing a response. To make it more readable, I've wrapped the completion handlers in `suspendCoroutine` so that I can just call readingSuspending and writeSuspending.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

object Test {

    val len = 1_000_000_000

    suspend fun AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.acceptSuspending() =
        suspendCoroutine<AsynchronousSocketChannel> { continuation ->
            this.accept(
                null, object : CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Nothing?> {
                    override fun completed(result: AsynchronousSocketChannel, attachment: Nothing?) {
                        continuation.resume(result)
                    }

                    override fun failed(exc: Throwable, attachment: Nothing?) {
                        continuation.resumeWithException(exc)
                    }
                })
        }

    suspend fun AsynchronousSocketChannel.writeSuspending(
        buffer: ByteBuffer,
        timeout: Duration = 60.seconds,
        closeWhenDone: Boolean = false,
    ) = suspendCoroutine<Int> { continuation ->
        this.write(buffer, timeout.inWholeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, null, object : CompletionHandler<Int, Nothing?> {
            override fun completed(size: Int, attachment: Nothing?) {
                continuation.resume(size)
            }

            override fun failed(exc: Throwable, attachment: Nothing?) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(exc)
            }
        })
    }

    suspend fun AsynchronousSocketChannel.readSuspending(
        buffer: ByteBuffer,
        timeout: Duration = 5.seconds,
    ) = suspendCoroutine<Int> { continuation ->
        this.read(buffer, timeout.inWholeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, null, object : CompletionHandler<Int, Nothing?> {
            override fun completed(size: Int, attachment: Nothing?) {
                continuation.resume(size)
            }

            override fun failed(exc: Throwable, attachment: Nothing?) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(exc)
            }
        }
        )
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {

        val server = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(InetSocketAddress(5555))
        }

        while (true) {
            val channel = server.acceptSuspending()
            supervisorScope {
                launch {
                    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000)

                    // reading
                    do {
                        val size = channel.readSuspending(buffer.rewind(), 30.seconds)
                        println(String(buffer.array().sliceArray(0..size)))
                    } while (!buffer.hasRemaining())

                    // build response
                    val body = "#".repeat(len)
                    val headers = mutableListOf<String>()
                    headers.add("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
                    headers.add("Server: Test Server")
                    headers.add("Content-Type: text/plain")
                    headers.add("Content-Length: ${body.length}")
                    val header = headers.joinToString(separator = "\r\n") + "\r\n\r\n"
                    val data = "$header$body".toByteArray()

                    // writing
                    channel.writeSuspending(ByteBuffer.wrap(data), 30.seconds)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        channel.close()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your implementation of `CompletionHandler` seems to be wrong: in `complete` you need to check whether buffer is empty or not, and if not empty reiterate `write` - keep reference to buffer in `CompletionHandler` or pass buffer as `attachment`

Comment: @andrey-b-panfilov, that should not make a difference in this context since I'm writing everything in one write. I've updated my question with source code which confirms this, same error.

Comment: still not clear if your code is actual or not. it got changed, however I do not see whether you read http request headers or not, cause w/o doing that `read` in `CompletionHandler` does not help.

Comment: I've updated the question with more code, see the EDIT, there's a full example including the coroutines I'm using. When doing a read first, the output size needs to be much bigger before hitting the connection reset error, but it's still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a socket programmer, just some thoughts...

Code is actually synchronous and all logic needs to be implemented inside `CompletionHandler`, however I believe it demonstrates the issue.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int len = 50_000_000;

    AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server =
            AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(5555));

    while (true) {
        try (AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = server.accept().get()) {
            // reading client headers, without that mitigation
            // of the race condition at the bottom of loop fails
            // one the other hand, I failed to reproduce the
            // problem when bottom read is commented out 
            System.out.println("Header: " + channel.read(ByteBuffer.allocate(4096)).get());
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                    "server: Cloud Auctioneers\r\n" +
                    "content-type: text/plain\r\n" +
                    // tell client to close socket
                    "connection: close\r\n" +
                    "content-length: " + len + "\r\n\r\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                body.append('#');
            }
            ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(body.toString().getBytes());
            // according to javadoc write method does not guarantee
            // that it will send the all data to client, at least
            // without this loop client receives just 256K on my laptop
            while (buff.hasRemaining()) {
                Integer written = channel.write(buff).get();
                System.out.println("Written: " + written);
                // not sure here about null
                if (written == null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // here we are trying to mitigate race condition between try-with-resources
            // and delivering pending data. according to man 2 send it sends data
            // asynchronously and there is no way to understand whether that was
            // successful or not - trying to read something from socket
            System.out.println("Footer: " + channel.read(ByteBuffer.allocate(4096)).get());
        }
    }
}
```

---

UPD. Have performed some research on the topic, below are some thoughts:

1. in case of writing to socket the code snippet like below:

```java
public <A> void completed(Integer result, A attachment) {
    if (result < 0) {
        // socket closed
        channel.close();
        return;
    }
    if (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        channel.write(buffer, null, this);
    }
}
```

seems to be mandatory due to following:

- it seems that `java.nio` does not route all errors to `CompletionHandler#failed`, have no idea why, that is what I observe
- it does not send full buffer to client - it could be reasonable because it is always a question what to do: `compact` buffer and populate it by pending data or send a reminder to client, however I would prefer to have a flag defining a behaviour in `AsynchronousSocketChannel#write`

2. In regard to the question who is responsible to close connection - the answer depends on the version of HTTP protocol (e.g. client):

- in case of HTTP/1.1 server may request client to close connection by sending HTTP header `Connection: close`
- in case of HTTP/1.0 server must to close connection by its own

  from infrastructure perspective the difference between those two cases is following: the side which initiates shutdown gets socket in `TIME_WAIT` state, and in case of server it is undesirable, so we also need to set `SO_REUSEADDR` to `true` (`SO_LINGER` is not supported in `AsynchronousSocketChannel`)

so, the implementation ultimately depends on the version on HTTP protocol, and here I would prefer to use existing library like `netty` rather than solving those `http` and `java.nio` puzzles, however the general idea is:

- read HTTP headers till '\r\n\r\n' or '\n\n', determine client version
- keep track of the amount of data written to client and reiterate
- close channel if IO returned -1 or exception thrown
- if client is HTTP/1.1 send `Connection: close` and wait for -1
- if client is HTTP/1.0 close channel

Comment: trying to read data from the socket when there's nothing to read, will block / suspend indefinitely. That `connection: close` HTTP header looks interesting, does that tell the browser to take care of closing the connection?
Ideally it's the browser that should be closing the connection since it knows when it's done reading the full response, but this also leaves the server open to DDOSS unless you add very short timeouts.

Comment: the same suggestion (perform read) here: https://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable. looks like it worth to add channel.shutdownOutput()

Comment: I've tried the channel.shutdownOutput() followed by a read and a close and if the read is too small or the body is too big, then I still run into the same issue.
So all the read is doing is the same as Thread.sleep()

I did give an upvote for the link to that brilliant article as that would help with general socket programming, but not when the client is the browser it seems.

Comment: The not closing the connection unless there's a `connection: close` header and continuing to read from the connection unless it's closed, fixed it or just responding with a header `connection: close` fixed it too, but then connections aren't recycled.

Something else was needed as well, when writing output, I had to write in 1kB or smaller blocks at a time, otherwise I would run into `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)` errors on AWS.

Making the write buffer smaller fixed the original error I was getting

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert [github](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/niodemo) - my attempt to implement what I have written.